# How to limit a job in gitlab ci to a tag matching a pattern?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I want to be able to trigger a deployment to a special server every time a tag matching a pattern is pushed.

I use the following job definition:

```
# ...
deploy to stage:
  image: ruby:2.2
  stage: deploy
  environment:
    name: foo-bar
  script:
    - apt-get update -yq
    - apt-get install -y ruby-dev
    - gem install dpl
#    - ...
  only:
    - tags
```

Now my question: how can I limit this to tags that have a certain name, for example starting with "V", so that I can push a tag "V1.0.0" and have a certain job running?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Only` [accepts regex patterns](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyexcept-basic) so for your use case it would be:

```
only:
  - /^V.*$/
except:
  - branches
  - triggers
```

Comment: Shouldn't we use only with tags and the regex instead of using except?

Comment: @ReAzem that would run for all tags OR regex. The logic goes like: `(only[1] OR only[2] ...) AND NOT (except[1] OR except[2] ...)`.

Comment: Perhaps this changed since 2018, but only chains with AND and except uses OR

- reference: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#onlyexcept-advanced

Comment: @L1Wulf hmm, well a hit yes and no. If you include multiple branch names withing only they will be evaluated as OR but they will be matched but all the different condition types will be an AND. I haven't used Gitlab in about so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 8):

Since [only / except are now being deprecated](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyexcept-basic), you should now prefer the `rules` keyword

Things get pretty simple, here's the equivalent using rules:

```
rules:
  # Execute only when tagged starting with V followed by a digit
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^V\d.*/
```

Answer (score 6):

The best way to do is filtering by the Gitlab CI/CD variables matching your pattern

```
only
  variables:
    - $CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^my-custom-tag-prefix-.*/
```

As the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) says:

- `CI_COMMIT_TAG`: The commit tag name. Present only when building tags.

Answer (score 0):

rules should help you here.
Below would restrict the job to run only if its triggered due to GIT Tag matching the pattern for e.g. V1.0.0 or V1.14.45 (see + after \d)

```
rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^V\d+.\d+.\d+$/'
      when: manual
```